# How to update records one by one identified by their minimum id and status

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a table ticket and I want to update the record which has a min(Ticket_ID) and the status is equal to open reservation. It works in the first execution of the query but when I have tried again nothing happens. All I want is to update it one by one look for the next lowest Ticket_ID that the status='Open for reservation'. I have tried different queries but it did not work.

[image: The first attempt it works:]

[image: The second attempt I was expecting Ticket_ID 35 will update the status next]

Comment: Your code wouldn't work in MySQL, so I'm confused by the tag.

Comment: I think the last WHERE criteria "Status = 'Open for reservation'" part should be part of the SELECT subquery instead of the UPDATE statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fix the condition.

```sql
UPDATE ticket SET Status="Closed" WHERE Ticket_ID = (SELECT Min(Ticket_ID) FROM ticket WHERE Status="Open");
```

In your second code, you are always looking for the minimum ticket id `27` AND `Status = 'OPEN'` which does not exist, so nothing updates.

Comment: @KimDaveTorres, please accept the answer for a kind gesture :)